# Not able to set s3 as remote backend from Azure devops Pipeline

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-devops, terraform

I am using azure devops classic pipeline for deploying infrastructure onto AWS, Steps I have followed

First created two Terraform for AWS plugin service connection with an access key and secret of an IAM user who had access as administrator into my target AWS account

I have replace token,terraform install, terraform init, terraform plan tasks where in terraform Init, I have configure amazon backend connection with which i created above...

```
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\terraform\1.5.6\x64\terraform.exe init -backend-config=bucket=iac-terraform -backend-config=key=tf/terraform.tfstate -backend-config=region=*** -backend-config=access_key=*** -backend-config=secret_key=***

Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...

Finding latest version of hashicorp/local...
Finding latest version of hashicorp/tls...
Finding latest version of hashicorp/template...
Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 3.0"...
Installing hashicorp/local v2.4.0...
Installed hashicorp/local v2.4.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
Installing hashicorp/tls v4.0.4...
Installed hashicorp/tls v4.0.4 (signed by HashiCorp)
Installing hashicorp/template v2.2.0...
Installed hashicorp/template v2.2.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
Installing hashicorp/aws v3.76.1...
Installed hashicorp/aws v3.76.1 (signed by HashiCorp)`
```

so i could see this task successful but on s3 bucket i dont see any state file created..'
struggling with this issue since last two days

so even if you define backend config in your provider main.tf, azure devops task value over rides it correct ? or we dont need to provide backed definition in provider main. tf as pipele terraform task already have backend config info since I am using classical pipeline... ?

the iam user which I have used have admin access and full access on s3
while i am this service connection, all input we give is access key, secret key and region, that means, based on access key and secret key it will determine which aws accounts it will connect ?

since IAM user is created at global level, so s3 bucket also global level right...
really not sure , task is successful but I dont see any terraform state file there ? how to debug this any idea...